# What effect does it have to return in an Extbase action in TYPO3 v10?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

e.g. an action does one of the following:

1. `return null;`
2. `return $aString;`
3. no return

What is the effect?

The documentation is not clear to me, e.g.

> As described in chapter 4 in section “controlling the flow”, it is not necessary to return the rendered content.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/7-Controllers/1-Creating-Controllers-and-Actions.html#flow-pattern-display-a-list-of-domain-objects

So what if you do return a string? Is this displayed instead of using the Fluid template? Is returning null the same as returning nothing?

---

In v11 it is different but I am asking for v10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TYPO3 10 returning a string will display that string and not render the Fluid template.  This is mostly useful if you want to display something other than HTML (like JSON for example, just use `return json_encode($values);`) or if you're getting your HTML from a different source (a webservice or a different templating system for example).

Returning null is the same as returning nothing. So this will trigger the Fluid template rendering as normal.